# MYSQL SUM for two several columns in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'll explain the scenario, formula one, there are 2 drivers to every team in formula 1, 24 drivers, 12 teams. I need to get the points calculated below from the team_stats table but get the poles, podiums and victories from the driver_stats table, so sebastion vettel and mark webber both are a member of team_id = '3' which is red bull. I need to get the poles, podiums, victories from the driver_stats table for each of them and sum them together, but calculate the points for the TEAM that there in from the team_stats table. What I have been encountering is that it is calculating the team points twice for each team_id because there are two drivers in the driver_stats table, where I need it just to do the SUM for the points in the team_stats table just for each team_id that the drivers are a member of.

```
DRIVER_STATS TABLE 
| track_id | drivers_id | qual_pos | race_pos | overtakes | points

TEAM STATS TABLE
| track_id | team_id | points |

DRIVERS TABLE
| driver_id | drivername | team_id |

TEAM TABLE COLUMNS 
|team_id | teamname | value
```

Now below this works but calculates the points from the driver_stats table, it does the sums for the overtakes poles etc.. correctly by adding the two drivers together. I need it to SUM the points part for each team_id in the team_stats table instead, there is only one occurence in that table for each 2 drivers in the driver_stats table, 2 drivers to 1 team.

```
    SELECT t.teamname,
         t.value,
         SUM(IF(s.qual_pos = '1', 1,0)) AS poles,
         SUM(IF(s.race_pos <= '3', 1,0)) AS podiums,
         SUM(IF(s.race_pos = '1', 1,0)) AS victories,
         SUM(s.overtakes) AS overtakes,
         SUM(CASE
           WHEN s.track_id = (SELECT MAX(track_id) FROM driver_stats) THEN
             points
           ELSE
             0
         End) AS lastracepoints,
         SUM(points) AS points 

   FROM         drivers d
   INNER JOIN  driver_stats s
   ON         d.drivers_id = s.drivers_id
   AND         d.team_id = 3
   LEFT JOIN  teams t
   ON         d.team_id = t.team_id
   GROUP BY
   t.teamname
```

This is the query I changed it too to try and achieve it.

```
       SELECT t.teamname,
         t.value,
         SUM(IF(s.qual_pos = '1', 1,0)) AS poles,
         SUM(IF(s.race_pos <= '3', 1,0)) AS podiums,
         SUM(IF(s.race_pos = '1', 1,0)) AS victories,
         SUM(s.overtakes) AS overtakes,
         SUM(CASE
           WHEN ts.track_id = (SELECT MAX(track_id) FROM team_stats) THEN
             ts.points
           ELSE
             0
         End) AS lastracepoints,
         SUM(ts.points) AS points 

   FROM          drivers d
   INNER JOIN  driver_stats s
   ON          d.drivers_id = s.drivers_id
   AND         d.team_id = 3
   LEFT JOIN  teams t
   ON          d.team_id = t.team_id
   INNER JOIN  team_stats ts
   ON          ts.team_id = d.team_id
   GROUP BY
   t.teamname
```

The numbers kinda go out of control now on this one by joining the team_stats to it and changing the sum points to team_stats, it looks like it is doing the sum in the team_stats table twice for each driver in the driver_stats table where i need it to be done once.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some sample data/output?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the ts.team_id join the t.team_id, and look into the INNER JOIN, you might be better of with another LEFT JOIN